# Promise: difference of await vs. just calling the function

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to understand async/await and understanding the difference of `await` vs. just calling the function as-is, would be synchronous anyways, right?

```
function foo() {
     this.doSomething(); // waits for this to run before going to next line
     return "1";
}

async foo() {
     await this.doSomething(); // waits for this to run before going to next line
     return "1";
}
```

aren't they both waiting for `doSomething()` to finish?

Comment: If `doSomething()` is asynchronous or does some asynchronous operation, then no, they're not the same.

Comment: Even if `this.doSomething()` is synchronous, the two aren't exactly the same. Whether the difference *matters* is another topic entirely. It's not really clear what you're asking or why since it seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

**If `doSomething()` is an `async` function or return a Promise:** then the first example doesn't wait for whatever happens inside `doSomething()` to complete. `doSomething()` will still be executed, but outside of `foo()` execution flow.

**If `doSomething()` is a synchronous function:** then both examples don't differ.

**More explanation:** The concept of `async/await` revolves around `Promise`, so to understand `async/await` you should understand `Promise` first.
A `Promise` consist of an asynchronous operation and a future return value of that asynchronous operation.

The `async` modifier makes a function asynchronous by making it return a `Promise`. Whenever you call an `async` function, the content of the function is actually wrapped into a `Promise` and executed outside of the calling site flow. A plain call of a `async` function will return a Promise instead of the value of the function.

```
async function intFunction() {
    return 1
}

function foo() {
    const result = intFunction(); // result is actually a Promise, not 1.
    
    console.log(result instanceof Promise); // should print true
}

foo();
```

The `await` keyword "waits out" a `Promise`. Whenever you call `await` with a `Promise`, the `Promise` is executed, the result is waited out and returned in the same execution context where you call it. Therefore, it only makes sense to be able to call `await` in a asynchronous context only, so you won't block the single thread of the JS engine.

```
async function intFunction() {
    return 1
}

async function foo() {
    const promise = intFunction();
    const value = await promise;
    console.log(value === 1); // should be true
}

foo(); 
// You can call an asynchronous function in the outermost context in running Node.js,
// the engine will wait for all those functions to finish before exiting.
```

Comment: "*If doSomething() is a synchronous function: then both examples don't differ.*" the second example would still pause for a tick before continuing. It's not 100% the same. Although, in most circumstances that doesn't matter.